# Result of database query as default value for Django model field?

Tags: python, django, django-models, default-value

models.py

```
class Aref5(models.Model):
    name = Aref5.objects.all.order_by('id')[0]
    Rthink = models.TextField(max_length=2000,  blank=True, default=name)
    <....>
```

I would like to have the `default` value of `Rthink` be the `id` of the the last item.

With the above code I get an error saying that `Aref5` is not recognized. How can I access existing `Aref5` instances within the definition of `Aref5`?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of problems here. One is that if this were to work, `name` would be computed once whenever Django started up, and every instance of `Aref5` would get the same default value. The other is that trying to access a class within its definition causes an error.

The `default` argument to a `TextField` (or any `Field` subclass) can be a callable instead of a value, in which case it will be called whenever a new object is created. Something like this should work:

```
Rthink = models.TextField(max_length=2000, blank=True, default=lambda: str(Aref5.objects.latest('id').id))
```

Since the expression involving `Aref5` appears inside a function body, it's not evaluated right away.

Comment: New docs: lambdas can’t be used for field options like default because they can’t be serialized by migrations. See that documentation for other caveats

Answer (score 0):

According to the recent [documentation for the default value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default) `This can be a value or a callable object. If callable it will be called every time a new object is created.`

`The default can’t be a mutable object (model instance, list, set, etc.), as a reference to the same instance of that object would be used as the default value in all new model instances. Instead, wrap the desired default in a callable.`

Example:

```
def contact_default():
    return {"email": "to1@example.com"}

contact_info = JSONField("ContactInfo", default=contact_default)
```

`lambdas can’t be used for field options like default because they can’t be serialized by migrations`