# How to automatically assign value in django models

Tags: django, django-models

I have a simple model class:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    place = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name='Place')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name='Name')
```

And I'd like to ask you, is there a possibility to automatically set as default value for place field as number of records in table + 1

so for example if there will not be records in table the system automatically change the line to

```
place = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name='Place', default='1')
```

Will be thankful for your help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value can be a callable. i.e: you can call a method on the class to compute what you want the value to be.

So you could do:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    def compute_default(self):
       return <compute default, from query>
    place = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name='Place', default=compute_default)
```

Here's another reference: [Result of database query as default value for Django model field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968602/result-of-database-query-as-default-value-for-django-model-field?rq=1)

Another option you might consider is to do this when the object is saved.
See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#what-happens-when-you-save

You could use a signal, or override the .save() method on the object.

Answer (score 0):

> And I'd like to ask you, is there a possibility to automatically set as default value for place field as number of records in table + 1

For this part, you dont have to do anything. django does that automatically. It is called "id" field. So in your Model, first record will have a id of 1, second record will have id of 2 and so on.
For other default value, you can use default keyword.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
place = models.CharField(max_length=25,verbose_name='Place',default="SomePlace")
name = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name='Name')
```